# instantiating a template class in CNI/C++ code

Tags: java, c++, gcc, gcj

I have been fooling around with CNI in order to interpolate Java and C++ code for the last few hours.

While I was looking the possibility to use the Java collections as a replacement for my old team missing `libstd`, I tried to create a `java.util.Stack` object and manipulate it.

However, the compiler (`gcc` and `gcj`, in that probably the same) seems to play his cheap tricks upon my innocent mind:

```
# gcc -g -I. test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:24:3: error: ‘java::util::Stack’ is not a template
   Stack<Person> *stack = new Stack<Person>();
   ^
test.cc:24:30: error: ‘java::util::Stack’ is not a template
   Stack<Person> *stack = new Stack<Person>();
```

(the Person object is well defined java class)

Only when I removed the type argument specification, It let me use the data-structure, as if the type argument was chosen to be`java.lang.Object`. The [CNI docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/About-CNI.html) seems to mention nothing about it at all! no words about templates indeed.

Does anyone know about using templates in CNI context? is it supported? I searched `google` and `stackoverflow` for answers, but couldn't come with the slightest clue. Any help will be appreciated.

In addition, I would like to know if i'm using a gcc 2.95.2 (is there a gcj for that gcc version?)

I am working on `Virtual Boxed` `Ubunto 12` over `windows 10` host. 
More importantly `gcj` and `gcc` versions stands on `4.8.4`
`java --version` yields `1.5` and `libgcj 4.8.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a CNI user, but the reason for this one seems to be obvious enough.

Generic specification `java.util.Stack<T>` in Java is only a compile time constraint that checks that you add objects of type compatible with T. Internally, `java.util.Stack` has only single implementation which accepts all types of `Object`s (actually, *references* to all types of objects). You may even trick compiler into addding not an instance of T by using unsafe conversions. So, `java.util.Stack<String>` and `java.util.Stack<Date>` are the same internally.

C++ is different. Instantiation of the same template with different arguments creates different incompatible types. For example, `std::stack<int>`, `std::stack<int*>` and `std::stack<char>` are totally different implementations and have different code. C++ template mechanism is a superset of java generics.

If, for example, you wanted to get Java functionality in C++, you would write `std::stack<void*>` even if you wanted to store objects of some particular type T. Type conversion to T has to be done manually.

CNI does the same thing. It instantiates the only one implementation of `java.util.Stack` which can accept all types of objects.

Comment: Yes, it does seem obvious after your explanation. I guess I should have come up with this myself. Thanks.